# Unable to import autoexplainer

Tags: azure, automl, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting the below error while trying to import autoexplainer in azureml:

```
from azureml.train.automl.automlexplainer import explain_model
```

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 from azureml.train.automl.automlexplainer import retrieve_model_explanation
>         2 from azureml.train.automl.automlexplainer import explain_model
>         3 
>         4 shap_values, expected_values, overall_summary, overall_imp, per_class_summary, per_class_imp = explain_model(fitted_model, x_train, x_test)
>         5 #Overall feature importance
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.train.automl.automlexplainer'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The package path has changed

It should be:-

from azureml.train.automl.runtime.automlexplainer import explain_model

Answer (score 0):

What version of azureml-train-automl are you using? The recent versions of azureml-train-automl, explain_model() is available in the package  azureml.train.automl.runtime.automlexplainer.

Can you try  azureml.train.automl.runtime.automlexplainer import explain_model?

Answer (score 0):

Using azureml.train.automl.runtime.automlexplainer worked for me. 
Thanks!

The version for azureml-train-automl was 1.0.85